# Fastest way to calculate "cosine" metrics with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, trigonometry

I am given a matrix of ones and zeros. I need to find 20 rows which have the highest cosine metrics towards 1 `specific` row in matrix:

If I have 10 rows, and 5th is called `specific`, I want to choose the highest value between these:
`cosine(1row,5row),cosine(2row,5row),...,cosine(8row,5row),cosine(9row,5row)`

First, i tried to count metrics. 
This didn't work:

```
A = ratings[:,100]
A = A.reshape(1,A.shape[0])
B = ratings.transpose()
similarity = -cosine(A,B)+1
A.shape = (1L, 71869L)
B.shape = (10000L, 71869L)
```

Error is: `Input vector should be 1-D.` I'd like to know, how to implement this aesthetically with no errors, but the most important - which solution will be the fastest?

In my opinion, the fastest way is not realized with help of `scipy`;
We just have to take all ones in `specific` row and look at these indices in all other rows. Those rows, which have the highest coincidence will have the highest matrix.

Are there any faster ways?

Comment: What do you mean saying `which have the highest cosine metrics towards 1 specific row in matrix`? Can you post sample data sets and desired data set?

Comment: Just so you know, there is a [cosine distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) function in scipy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but it wiil count all distances(between all elements ~ O(n!)) This is very irrational

Comment: @MaxU its done now

Comment: You need to clarify your question: how to accomplish this (you are getting an error, for example) or how to squeeze as much performance out of it. If you use [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html#sklearn-metrics-pairwise-cosine-similarity) that will use BLAS under the hood. Probably that is approaching the fastest way.

Comment: Also, what are the dimensions of your matrix?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i will add it right now

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995263/is-there-a-specific-use-of-pdist-function-of-scipy-for-some-particular-indexes/38997940#38997940; change `metric='hamming'` to `metric='cosine'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is to use matrix operations: `something like np.multipy(A,B)`